# Regex inverse match

Tags: flex-lexer, regex-negation

I'm developing my lexer with flex and I need to create a rule that matches `''` (two single quotes) and a rule that matches anything but two single quotes. The first part is easy, just a `\'\'` does the job, but I'm not sure how to write the other rule. I guess it needs to be some kind of inverse regex, but I'm not familiar with flex regex.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean exactly by "anything other than two single quotes"? Any string of any length which does not contain `''`? Any two characters other than `''`? The shortest string up to the next occurrence of `''`?

The third option is the only one which makes sense to me in the context of lexical analysis; its corresponding regular expression is:

```
([']?[^'])+
```

(That is, any sequence of characters in which a `'`, if it occurs, is followed by something other than another `'`.)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this rule:

```
([^']+|\'[^']+)+|([^']+|\'[^']+)+\'$
```

since you define an other rule: `''` and since flex will take the longest match for a position. This rule can't match two (or more) consecutive quotes, and allows a single quote at the end of the string.

Comment: flex complains about unrecognized rule

Answer (score 0):

For the second task, split the string with the delimeter `''`. So you have all substring which does not contain the delimeter and separated by it.

Comment: and what would be the regex for that?

Comment: Does someone hurts you if you don't use regex?

Comment: do you mean `strtok`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in flex:

`(([^'])|(\'[^']))+`

An explanation:

`[^']` matches any character but a single quote.

`\'[^']` matches a single quote followed by any other character.

EDIT: added in extra parens to ensure correct precedence.

Comment: `([^']|\'[^'])+` is just fine. The extra parentheses are just confusing IMHO. (However, the regex is still more complicated than necessary.)

Comment: To each their own...I prefer the extra parens.  But you are right, the regular expression you came up with is better.